# How to recover dual boot of two Ubuntu 15.10 systems?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I can no longer boot into my Ubuntu 15.10 sytem.
I'd like to know what I did wrong, and how best to fix it.
I can fix it by restarting from scratch, but it would be better to know why it's gone pear shaped!

My background is all windows up to a week or so ago.  Since then it's been Ubuntu 15.10, and it was all going very well up to this evening.

My system has two SSDs, and the primary Ubuntu 15.10 was installed on one.  A second Ubuntu 15.10 system was then installed on half of the second SSD, with the remaining half available to either system.  All seemed to work fine, and I could boot into either system.

The next step was to use fsarchiver to back up the primary system, and again went well, in that it created the ssd1archive.fsa file.  I only backed up the Ubuntu partition, not the boot or swap areas.

All fine at this point, I had a primary system, and a way to back it up using a second system.

To check it could restore, the primary system was used to run fsarchiver, and the ssd1archive.fsa was restored to the second SSD, which I expected to replace it's existing Ubuntu 15.10 with a copy of the primary system.

Again, all seemed to work fine, but I've just rebooted and found no menu, and instead a grub> prompt. No obvious way to access either Ubuntu system.

I didn't expect a restore of the ssd1archive.fsa to have any effect at all on the boot process, but clearly something has.

Any info on what I did wrong, and how best to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: "No obvious way to access Ubuntu", have you tried explicitly pointing GRUB to ther kernel/initrd then booting?

Comment: I'm just looking at grub> for the first time.

Comment: Okay. Please run `ls` in the GRUB prompt and let me know the output.

Comment: Have found cat (hd0,gpt2)/etc/issue replies with Ubuntu 15.10 \n \l

Will take a few mins to get the ls info.

Comment: If (hd0,gpt2) is your Ubuntu partition you can boot from it with the commands `linux (hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz` ... `initrd (hd0,gpt2)/initrd.img` and `boot`. Test it.

Comment: Reply to ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)

Comment: Test response was  another prompt, fs something.  Can't remember.

Comment: Oh, I know. Initramfs. It means the system failed to load your filesystem and fell back to the initial ramdisk filesystem. Something is wrong with your system.

Comment: boot-repair fixed the dual boot menu, so it's all back working.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The following fixed it:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I'd still like to know why it broke. I don't see why an fsarchiver partition restore should lose the grub menu.  Anyway boot-repair is quite quick.

Comment: Did the restore create a new partition with a new UUID? Or did it duplicate UUID (or GUID) which system cannot have. And if booting with UEFI, the grub.cfg in the ESP - efi system partition uses UUID to find install to boot. If two drives better to have an ESP on each drive, but grub does not let you directly install to anything but an ESP on sda. You have to manually copy to an ESP on sdb and manually maintain it. Or use rEFInd.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed it: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).
I'd still like to know why it broke. I don't see why an fsarchiver partition restore should lose the grub menu. Anyway boot-repair is quite quick.